# How can I remove a text appearing in quotes after tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is what I have:

```
<div class="inner">
   <a href="">Some Text</a>
   ".     "
   <a href="">Some Other Text</a>
   ".     "
</div>
```

I don't have access to javascript, HTML, or Jquery files. The only way I can edit this is using CSS. How can I remove ".   " from the above HTML?

Also, is there a way to remove the second anchor tag leaving the first intact? They both don't have class or id names.

Comment: CSS can only target elements. text-nodes are outside of CSS's purview.

Comment: @DerekS you're right. It's a duplicate. Sorry, I missed that. And the solution provided there solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you will have just two `a`, you can do something like this to remove the last one (the second one)

```
.inner a:last-child{display:none}
```

unfortunately i don't know hot to remove the `". "`

Comment: As @DerekS mentioned, there already's an answer on how to remove ".  ", and it worked. I'll also select your response as an answer since it solved the other issue.

Answer (score 8):

Use visibility property, not display. You can try this:

```
.inner {
     visibility: hidden;
 }
.inner a:first-child {
     visibility: visible;
 }
```

Comment: I would add a `:first-child` to the `.inner a` selector as he did not want the second `a` showing either.

Comment: +1 @Johannes Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to necessarily *remove* it, you can always *hide* it with a font-size of '0'. You can do this by using the following css:

```
.inner{
    font-size:0;
}
.inner a{
    font-size: //your font size
}
```

Again, this is not removing the '.' but hiding it from the client's view.